# rsync over ssh but block changes to authorized_keys file on remote computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync

OK I finally got rsync over ssh setup with authorized keys. Since I don't want my users browsing the filesystem, I have modified the authorized_keys file to run an rsync script. That way they can't do anything but my rsync script.

But, I want to make it so that the user can not replace that authorized_keys file or delete it.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file **and** its parent `~/.ssh` directory owned by root, and take away permission to edit the file yourself.

Comment: OK I just tried that and now a password is required to login as I can't even read the directory...how would I grant read only access to the user but full control to root?